# React - install react-table

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, cdn, react-table

I am trying to install [react-table](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-table#installation) but I am having trouble setting up the CDN. My current index.html file is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Code_LMS</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css" />
        <!-- change this up! http://www.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/ -->
        <!-- <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.3.6/cosmo/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/> -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>

    <body background="EasyMed.png">
        <div id="app"></div>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="bundle.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Can anyone please tell me where I should place the links/script mentioned in the CDN in my index.html file a way that doesn't mess up my dependencies? Thank you!

Comment: Try adding after bootstrap.

Comment: You mean adding after where I have provided the link to the bootstrap stylesheet?

Comment: And should i add all the sources provided (links + scripts) in the head tag?

Comment: Yes it should work, check the example in the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
class App extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return ( <
      div >
      <
      ReactTable columns = {
        [{
            Header: "Name",
            columns: [{
                Header: "First Name",
                accessor: "firstName"
              },
              {
                Header: "Last Name",
                id: "lastName",
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            Header: "Info",
            columns: [{
                Header: "Age",
                accessor: "age"
              },
              {
                Header: "Status",
                accessor: "status"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            Header: 'Stats',
            columns: [{
              Header: "Visits",
              accessor: "visits"
            }]
          }
        ]
      }
      defaultPageSize = {
        10
      }
      className = "-striped -highlight" /
      >
      <
      br / >
      <
      /div>
    );
  }
}



ReactDOM.render( <
  App / > ,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Code_LMS</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css" />
<!-- change this up! http://www.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/ -->
<!-- <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.3.6/cosmo/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/> -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<body background="EasyMed.png">
  <div id="app"></div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="bundle.js"></script>
  <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
  <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
  <!-- CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/react-table@latest/react-table.css">

  <!-- JS -->
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-table@latest/react-table.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-table@latest/react-table.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    var ReactTable = window.ReactTable.default
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: I copy pasted the body part of the second code snippet you shared but its still not working. I get the error: ERROR in ./node_modules/react-table/react-table.css
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type. I'm using style-loader to load .css files which is specified through webpack. Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Nevermind I got it to work! I suspected from the error that there was some .css loader problem happening so I added css-loader to the list of loaders for css in addition to style-loader in my webpack.config file and it worked! Thank you for yout answer!